# Tooltip for flagging chat messages is wrong

Tags: bug, chat, tooltips, chat-flags

When trying to flag a message in a chatroom's starboard, the tooltip whilst hovering over the flag button is `click to star`.

[image: Screenshot of tooltip]

[image: HTML of element]

Comment: development by copypaste

Comment: Some time later, this is still not fixed, although I tested with already-starred messages.